# .htaccess и перенаправление

Tags: .htaccess

Добрый день.

Как настроить .thaccess, чтоб все запросы переходили на `index.php`, но запросы, имеющие вид `mysite.com/api/......`, перенаправлялись на `api.php`, т.е.   url  `mysite.com/info1`, `mysite.com/info2`, `mysite.com/id1/param`   на `index.php`, а url  `mysite.com/api/getinfo`                                     на `api.php`.

Этот код перенаправляет всё, а мне нужно отфильтровать api:

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Как это сделать?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Переда вашим правилом следует добавить правило обрабатывающее запросы начинающиеся с подстроки `/api/` вот так:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/api\/
RewriteRule .* api.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

P.S. Файлы `api.php` и `index.php` должны реально существовать на сервере, чтобы не возникло зацикливание.